# serial port: bytes from device all have their most significant bit = 0

Tags: c++, linux, unix, serial-port

guys tell me please what can be a problem - i send commands (sequence of bytes including bytes with most significant bit (MSB) = 1) to device through serial port, device successfully recognize the commands (so it seems all bytes are sent correct) and reply with almost correct answer. "Almost" here means than answer is correct except that all bytes have zero MSB (while some of them must have MSB = 1).
I use Ubuntu 16 on VirtualBox, Windows 7 as host OS, serial port as USB device on FTDI chip.
Here my serial port settings:

```
void com::open()
{
    fd = ::open( "/dev/ttyUSB0", O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY | O_NDELAY );
    if ( fd < 0 )
    {
        throw exceptionSystem( ERROR_UNK, "Error open COM port" );
    }

    int err;
    err = fcntl(fd, F_SETFL, FNDELAY);
    if ( err == -1 )
    {
        close();
        throw exceptionSystem( ERROR_UNK, "Error fcntl" );
    }

    try{
        set();
    }catch(...){
        close();
        throw;
    }
}

void com::set()
{
    if ( fd == -1 )
        return;

    struct termios tty;
    memset( &tty, 0, sizeof( tty ) );
    if ( tcgetattr(fd, &tty) != 0 )
    {
        throw exceptionSystem( ERROR_UNK, "Error tcgetattr" );
    }

    int err;
    err = cfsetospeed( &tty, B115200 );
    if ( err != 0 )
    {
        throw exceptionSystem( ERROR_UNK, "Error fsetospeed" );
    }
    err = cfsetispeed( &tty, B115200 );
    if ( err != 0 )
    {
        throw exceptionSystem( ERROR_UNK, "Error cfsetispeed" );
    }

    tty.c_cflag &= ~CSIZE;
    tty.c_cflag |= CS8;
    tty.c_cflag |= PARENB;
    tty.c_cflag &= ~PARODD;
    tty.c_cflag &= ~CSTOPB;
    tty.c_cflag |= CLOCAL;
    tty.c_cflag |= CREAD;
    tty.c_cflag &= ~CRTSCTS;

    tty.c_lflag &= ~(ICANON | ECHO | ECHOE | ISIG);

    tty.c_iflag |= (INPCK | ISTRIP);
    tty.c_iflag &= ~IGNPAR;
    tty.c_iflag &= ~PARMRK;
    tty.c_iflag &= ~(IXON | IXOFF | IXANY);

    tty.c_oflag &= ~OPOST;

    tty.c_cc[VMIN]  = 0;
    tty.c_cc[VTIME] = 0;

    if ( tcsetattr( fd, TCSANOW, &tty ) != 0 )
    {
        throw exceptionSystem( ERROR_UNK, "Error tcsetattr" );
    }
}
```

Comment: Clearing all those bits with `&= ~` is futile when the flag word is already zero. Don't write useless code.

Comment: Or even better: for documentation purposes, write it and then comment it out! That shows that you know what exact settings you want, and yet not get the compiler to emit extra code.

Comment: @EJP not sure they are zero after `tcgetattr`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**EDIT** I've just seen the problem. You've got the line

```
tty.c_iflag |= (INPCK | ISTRIP);
```

`ISTRIP` means "strip off the eighth bit". You need

```
tty.c_iflag |= INPCK;
```

to simply enable input parity.

---

You've enabled EVEN parity

```
tty.c_cflag |= PARENB;
tty.c_cflag &= ~PARODD;
```

as well as 8-bit bytes

```
tty.c_cflag &= ~CSIZE;
tty.c_cflag |= CS8;
```

So that's one start bit, 8 data bits, 1 parity bit, and 1 stop bit. I'm not sure that the FTDI chip can handle all that!

If you don't want parity, use

```
tty.c_cflag &= ~PARENB;
```

And if I've maligned the FTDI chip, I apologise - in which case are you sure the other end is configured the same way? `8E1` is not very common compared to `7E1` or `8N1`

Comment: For such settings - i follow a device manual. It says it use "data length: 8bit + 1 parity; 1 stop bit; character code: ASCII 8 bit code; vertical (even) parity check".

Comment: In that case, you shouldn't have `ISTRIP` on `c_iflag`. See my edit above

Comment: That is right. Thanks. I thought ISTRIP strips parity bits as stated by some internet pages which i found.